# Express $\sin(ax)$ in terms of $\sin(bx)$ or/and $\cos(bx)$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to express $\sin(ax)$ in terms of $\sin(bx)$ or/and $\cos(bx)$ ?

That is, $\sin(ax)$ is a function of $\sin(bx)$ or/and $\cos(bx)$,

where x only exists inside $\sin(bx)$ or/and $\cos(bx)$.
$$\sin(ax) = f_1(\sin(bx)) \quad \vee \quad \sin(ax) = f_2(\cos(bx)) \quad \vee \quad \sin(ax) = f_3(\sin(bx), \cos(bx))$$

I want to find either of the functions $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$.

Comment: Is $\sin{ax}=\sqrt{\left( \cos{ax}\right)^2-1}$ allowed?

Comment: No because $\sin(ax)$ is not a function of $\cos(ax)$ but $\cos(bx)$.

Comment: What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @mrp I think the idea is that there is any relationship.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall then take $a = b$.

Comment: @mrp No, I mean an arbitrary relationship, any *given* relationship. i.e. No relationship.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall I'm not disagreeing with you, just trying to point out that this is not clear from the question, nor whether $a$ and $b$ be can be negative, irrational, etc.

Comment: @mrp I know, I understood exactly what you meant; the parameters of the problem were ill-defined, for sure.

Comment: @mrp: Judging by a comment under YuriyS' answer, the OP wants to use such a formula to program a synthesizer. Since software only deals with rational numbers (with a finite numbers of decimals), it is safe to assume that $a$ and $b$ are rational, with no particular relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with complex numbers. If you are allowed to use complex numbers, then use Euler's identity: $\Bbb e ^{\Bbb ix} = \cos x + \Bbb i \sin x$.

Then you get

$$
\sin ax = \frac {\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i ax} - \Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i ax}} {2 \Bbb i} = \frac {(\Bbb e^ {\Bbb i bx})^\frac a b - (\Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i bx})^\frac a b} {2 \Bbb i} .
$$

Using Euler's identity again for $\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i bx}$ and $\Bbb e  ^{-\Bbb i bx}$: $\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i bx} = \cos bx + \Bbb i \sin bx$ you get

$$\sin ax = \Bbb i \frac {(\cos bx - \Bbb i \sin bx)^\frac a b - (\cos bx + \Bbb i \sin bx)^\frac a b} 2 .$$

I also used the property of the imaginary unit $\frac 1 {\Bbb i} = -\Bbb i$.

---

To make my answer more useful, here is how we can evaluate $(\cos bx \pm \Bbb i \sin bx)^\frac a b$ for any real $a, b$

If $\cos bx \geq \sin bx$

$$(\cos bx \pm \Bbb i \sin bx)^\frac a b=\cos bx ^{ \frac a b } (1 \pm i \tan bx)^\frac a b$$

Which is binomial series and can be expanded.

If $\cos bx \leq \sin bx$

$$(\cos bx \pm \Bbb i \sin bx)^\frac a b=(-i \sin bx )^{ \frac a b } (1 \pm i \tan^{-1} bx)^\frac a b$$

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!this may help me create an algorithme for an additive synthesizer.

Comment: Hmm... And how do you evaluate $(\cos bx + \Bbb i \sin bx)^{\frac a b}$ without getting back to complex exponentials? (Note that $\frac a b$ may be a real number.)

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict yourself to the real numbers, then it is not possible in general.

For example, take $a=1$ and $b=2$. Given any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$$
but since $\sin 2(x+\pi) = \sin 2x$ and $\cos 2(x+\pi) = \cos 2x$, no function of $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ can have this property.